# Do I need to complete SEP IRA deposit before April 15 (United States)?

Tags: united-states, taxes, sep-ira

On my 2018 U.S. tax return (already filed) I indicated that I would contribute a certain amount to a SEP IRA.

I just initiated a deposit in the correct amount to my SEP account at Vanguard, but funds are being transferred from my bank account, and the transfer may not be complete before midnight on April 15.

If the transfer is not complete by the end of April 15, will I still be able to count it as a 2018 contribution, given that I initiated the contribution today (April 12)?

If not, is there anything I can do (short of filing an amended return and paying taxes on the income that was supposed to be deferred via the SEP) to avoid potential issues with the IRS for not having made the 2018 SEP contribution that I said I would?